# Ubuntu 16.04.6 Purple Screen Stuck

Tags: boot, grub2, screen

I used ubuntu version 16.04.6 System Property Dual Xeon CPU
2.7 GHZ 256 GB RAM DUAL GTX 1080

Problems; As we know, server systems can be open for a long time.

I closed it 2 days to rest this week.

When I wanted to turn it back on it gave a pink screen at the beginning.

I have tried all the methods written before.

Nomodeset,Fsck,Boot repair.

however, I did not get any positive results. I cannot enter the terminal. I cannot enter recovery mode. I cannot enter the recovery set section. I cannot update in any way.I Change thıs GRUB Default. I cannot CTRL + ALT F1+F2+F3 .... I would really appreciate if you can help.

Thank you for your interest.